# React JS MediaRecorder not a constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-audio, audio-recording

I am trying to build an App in which you can Record Audio on all Browsers. (Chrome, Firefox, Safari +11). 
So I am using the "audio-recorder-polyfill" Library to eypose it to React.

The problem is now, that if I try to call

```
new MediaRecorder(stream);
```

I get an error saying:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): 
__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_audio_recorder_polyfill__.MediaRecorder is 
not a constructor
```

Now I saw examples where people dont have that problem. I just dont know where to start as I am not using Typescript as well.

The compiler can see and recognizes
`const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true});`
But thats it.

Help would really be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which polyfills are you using ? can you point us to those please ... ?

Comment: Hey 82Tuskers, thanks for the help, I dont quite remember what I did there but I was able to fix it.
Sometimes it is as easy as simply following the given tutorial.

To answer your question though, I am using this: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/audio-recorder-polyfill